# Copying/Creating files on TimeCapsule/Mac using Ubuntu 12.04 and afp

Tags: macos, ubuntu, afp

I have a TimeCapsule that I am currently just using as an external hard drive (not using time machine) and a Mac laptop.

Using a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 installation, I am able to connect to the hard drive/mac and can navigate the folders using nautilus (I can do this through by viewing the hard drive/mac in the network folder). I can view and delete any files or folders that already exist on the hard drive/mac.

However, if I attempt to create a file (or copy a file) from the Ubuntu instance on the hard drive/mac, I get the following error:

> kFPMiscError

What is also weird is that the file appears to be created (i.e. it appears in the folder when I view it from my Mac, but it's empty).

Any help in getting this to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, good news and bad news.  It has to do with the AFP (Apple File Protocol) Server.  Here's the complete error message

`kFPMiscErr    -5014   An unspecified error occurred`

The reason I'm posting this as an answer is this, this is not a function of something Ubuntu is doing.  To the best of my knowledge there is no error console on your time capsule, so there is nothing to tell you what went wrong, and no way to find out.  At this point, I'd call Apple for support.

Comment: Hey, this also happens on my Mac laptop. Is there a way to troubleshoot this using the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use SAMBA instead. TimeMachine can be configured to use SAMBA (there is a checkbox somewhere in its settings) and linux can play well with the SAMBA protocol.

I have a time machine being accessed by two different linux boxes and 3-4 Macs with no problem. It even works when someone brings a windows laptop to the house!